# Product showing out of stock but In stock in backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.5p1

We have some products in our inventory that are in-stock in the backend but showing out-of-stock in frontend.
If I make a product out-stock and then back to in-stock then it works fine( in-stock in frontend).
We are updating inventories using a third party(Linnworks).

I am not getting actual issues, let me know if someone has faced such issues.

Magento 2.4.5-p1 version.

Comment: First make sure with inventory table. is_in_stock should be true on cataloginventory_stock_item table.

Comment: =>SELECT qty, is_in_stock FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` where product_id = "YOUR ID";

Comment: => SELECT product_id,stock_status FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status`  where product_id = "YOUR ID";

Comment: @S.P cataloginventory_stock_item table shows is_in_stock =1 but table cataloginventory_stock_status shows is_in_stock = 0 and qty > 0 

Not updating even after reindex.

Comment: So may be the issue from third party Linnworks module or indexing.

It would be update when you build index.

Comment: execute bellow command again and clean cache.

Comment: bin/magento indexer:reset;

Comment: bin/magento indexer:reindex; bin/magento cache:flush;

Comment: Tried all but nothing works, need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Update quantity and also make sure you should have default stock greater than 0.